# JQuery:Not able to fetch value of "td" when onclick on button happens second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

Following is the code of my table. In the action column i have a buttons named accept and reject. On click on reject I want to get the values of 2 and 3 "td" present in that "tr".

```
<table class="w3-table" id="tbl_task" width="100%">
<tr>
    {% for ele in d|slice:":1" %} {% for key in ele.keys %}
    <th>{{ key }}</th>
    {% endfor %} {% endfor %}
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
{% for ele in d %}
<tr class="class_1">
    {% for k, v in ele.iteritems %} {% if k in "Assigned_Users" %}
    <td>
        {% if v|length > 2 %}
        <div style="width: 80%;max-height: 37px;overflow:auto;margin-left: 32px;">
            {% for ch in v %} {{ ch|linebreaksbr }} {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% else %} {% for ch in v %} {{ ch }} {% endfor %} {% endif %}
    </td>
    {% else %}
    <td>
        {{ v }}
    </td>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
    <td class="noexcel">
        <div id="td_button_div">
            <button id="status_accepted" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="accept">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Approve
            </button>
            <button id="status_rejected" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="reject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Reject
            </button>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <label>Remarks</label>
                            <textarea name="textarea" style="color:black;width:100%"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_remarks">Save changes
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

At first time I am getting data properly but at second click only modal is displayed with the existing values.

Following is my JQuery code:

```
$('#status_rejected').on('click', function(e){

        var current_row = ' ';
        var task_name = ' ';
        var current_status = ' ';
        var notes = ' ';

        alert("inside reject function");

        current_row = $(this).closest('tr');

        task_name = current_row.find("td:eq(2)").text();

        current_status = current_row.find("td:eq(0)").text();

        alert("cstatus--->"+$.trim(current_status)+"\n"+"tname"+$.trim(task_name));
        var status = "reject"

        $("textarea").val(" ");

        $("#save_remarks").on('click',function(){
            alert("inside save changes on click");

            notes = $.trim($("textarea").val());
            alert("cstatus"+$.trim(current_status)+"\n"+"tname"+$.trim(task_name));


        });
});// end of show model
```

Need help with this?

Comment: you mean if the user clicked that button then he refresh the page you want to disallow him from clicking the button again?

Comment: Hey can you put the generated HTML here?  Simply look at the source inside your web browser and then copy and paste it into the answer.  One issue I see is you're using id's.  You should only have one id for one element on a webpage, use a class for status_rejected instead.

Comment: @nfnneil I tried it but it is not working

Comment: Tried which one?  Getting the source code or the switching the id to a class?

Comment: @nfnneil I am getting the values but on problem i am facing is when for the first time i select the reject button i am getting the value from "status" and "task" properly. But at second time I am getting the previous as well as the newly selected values.

Comment: When you transition to the next one, are you removing the previous td's?

Comment: @nfnneil No i am not removing it. Instead i am changing the status there itself and if user reloads page then that data would not be displayed as all the data is cmg through DB.

Comment: @nfnneil Is there way to clear the variables which i have used inside jquery after modal is hidden

Answer (score 0):

I was able resolve this in the following way:

```
$('.noexcel #status_rejected').on('click', function(e){

            var current_row = ' ';
            var task_name = ' ';
            var current_status = ' ';
            var notes = ' ';
            var cnt = 0;

            current_row = $(this).closest('tr');

            task_name = current_row.find("td:eq(2)").text();

            current_status = current_row.find("td:eq(0)").text();

            var status = "reject"

            $("textarea").val(" ");

            $("#save_remarks").on('click',function(){

                notes = $.trim($("textarea").val());

                if(current_status != ' ' && task_name != ' ' && notes != ' ' && current_row != ' '){
                    ajax_call(current_row, current_status, task_name, notes, status);
                    current_row = current_status = task_name = notes = ' ';
                }
            }); // end of onclick of modal save button
    });// end of show model

function ajax_call(current_row, current_status, task_name, notes, status){
    $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'/ajax/change_ftrack_status/',
            data:{
                currentStatus : current_status,
                taskName : task_name,
                status : status,
                notes : notes
            },
            success:function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                if (key == "ftrack_status"){
                    current_row.find("td:eq(0)").html(value);
                }
                else if (key == "updated_on"){
                    current_row.find("td:eq(1)").html(value);
                }
            }); // end of for each
            // disable the reject button
            current_row.find("td #status_rejected").prop("disabled", true);
            }
           }); //end of ajax
}
```